# How to set schedule tasks from another scripts? (kivy in pure python)

Tags: python, kivy, schedule

I have several scripts. In the main script of the application, I create a text document with the answers (123.txt).

Also I am creating another text file with the schedule (test_schedule.txt). From this schedule, I pass 2 arguments (.do(test_func, 123)) to a script (test_schedule.py) that runs after the main application is closed.

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. If I write

exec(open(f"./test_schedule.py").read())

before closing the application
(Test().stop())

then I get an error:
NameError: name 'schedule' is not defined

If I write
exec(open(f"./test_schedule.py").read())

after closing the application
(Test().stop())

then scheduled task works, but the application window does not close and not responding.
Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Here is my main application code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

now = datetime.now()

Window.size = (240, 480)
Window.clearcolor = (180 / 255, 90 / 255, 3 / 255, 1)
Window.title = "Test"


class Setup(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Setup, self).__init__(**kw)

        my_list = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'white', 'magenta', 'cian']

        grid = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=10, spacing=3)

        label = Label(text=f'{my_list}', size_hint=(1, None), halign="left", valign="middle")
        label.bind(size=label.setter('text_size'))
        grid.add_widget(label)

        grid.add_widget(
            Button(text='submit', background_color=(0, 1, 1, 1), pos_hint=(None, 1), size_hint_y=None,
                   height=60,
                   on_press=lambda x: self.on_stop(my_list)))

        self.add_widget(grid)

    def on_stop(self, x):
        with open('123.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as test:  # text file with answers
            print(f'{x}', file=test)
            created_at = datetime.now()
            time_change = timedelta(minutes=1)
            new_time = created_at + time_change  # time set to current time + 1 minute
            print(new_time.strftime("%H:%M"))

        with open('schedule_list_test.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as schedule:  # text file with schedule
            print(f'schedule.every().day.at("{new_time.strftime("%H:%M")}").do(test_func, 123)', file=schedule)

        # exec(open(f"./test_schedule.py").read())  # if I place here I get error

        Test().stop()


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Setup(name='setup'))


class Test(App):
    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kvargs)

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()

exec(open(f"./test_schedule.py").read()) # if I place here app window is not responding
```

here is the script (test_schedule.py) that runs after main script:

```
import schedule
import time
import sys


class Scheduler:
    my_list = None
    with open("schedule_list_test.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as s_list:
        line = s_list.readline()
        a = line.strip('\n')
        my_list = a

    def __init__(self):
        exec(self.my_list)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)


def test_func(x):
    sys.argv = ["./test_run.py", x]
    return exec(open(f"./test_run.py").read())


scheduler = Scheduler()
```

here is the script (test_run.py) that runs for print answers from text file with answers:

```
from sys import argv


script_name, execute = argv

with open(f"{execute}.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as q_list:
    content = q_list.readline()
    print(content)
```

Sorry, I'm new to programming and my code probably looks terrible.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Considering it's `NameError: name 'schedule' is not defined`  and not `NameError: name ./test_schedule.py'` is not defined it's probably an error in ./test_schedule.py

Looking at ./test_schedule.py the first line `import schedule`
name schedule is not defined - the library is not installed

Comment: sorry for naming .txt file with the same name from .py, but there are different files, in txt file I write command for schedule, and in .py file I run script to check time. I will try to rename files right now

Comment: I edited my scripts, now names for files are different, thank you for this remark! Still hoping for help with my scheduler :)

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer now

Comment: No, this is definitely not the case, since the schedule works if I run it after stop(). But in this case, the application window does not close and not responding. And I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Why don't you package it as a library though? exec open is ugly python

Comment: If you add ./test_schedule.py to main app code, you will not get any errors

Comment: I tried to import test_schedule.py but the app window is still not responding after this script start executing... now I read documentation about coroutines and asyncio, maybe it will help to close the window without freezing..

Comment: Maybe, Python can only execute one line at a time (without asyncio)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me :) if I find a solution, I will  update this thread.